# Extract vector elements that appear in a data frame column?

Tags: r, regex

Example data:

```
vec <- c(21, 23, 25)
df <- data.frame(lines=c("line_21.1", "line_21.2", "line_25.1", "line_25.2", "line_223.1", "line_223.2"), values=c(1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2))

df

lines      values
line_21.1  1
line_21.2  3
line_25.1  4
line_25.2  2
line_223.1 2
line_223.2 2
```

I would like to subset only the elements of `vec` which are included in `df$lines`. So my desired output for this example would be:

```
vec2

21, 25
```

I tried this:

```
 vec2 <- sapply(vec, function(x) grep(x, df$lines))
```

But this causes 23 to be incorrectly included due to the 223 entry:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1, 2

[[2]]
[1] 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 3, 4
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> num <- gsub(".*_(\\d+).*", "\\1", df$lines)
> vec[vec %in% num]
[1] 21 25
```

Comment: Both of these approaches are correct as long as the OP doesn't have duplicates in the 'vec'.  If that is the case, your approach is more correct.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gsub` to remove the substring in 'lines' and then do an `intersect` to get the elements common in both

```
vec2 <- intersect(gsub(".*_|\\.\\d+", "", df$lines), vec)
vec2
#[1] 21 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Small modification to your vec2 calculation. This should work

```
vec2 <- sapply(vec, function(x) grep(paste("_",x,".",sep = ""), df$lines))
```